# Notepad++: Rule based line highlighting

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

Is there a way to automatically highlight lines based on predefined rules in Notepad++?

I'm not talking about syntax highlighting, but rather about log files readability.

I'm looking either for a feature I've missed, or a plugin.

Comment: Would line hiding suffice?  I'm thinking hiding lines that you don't want to see so that you can more easily see the important lines.

Comment: @MBraedley - That sounds useful, how do you do that? But for my usecase it's not a good solution, I need to see many lines of log and coloring them based on their contents would help me greatly

Comment: Line hiding is under TextFX->TextFX Viz.

Answer (score 8):

1. Select `Language` > `Define your language...` (or `View Language` > `User-Defined Dialog...`, or `Language > User-Defined`, depending on version and localisation file)
2. Use the *User-Defined dialogue* to specify what to highlight. To highlight certain words, use the *Keyword Lists* tab and enter each word in a *Group*, selecting *Colour/Font style* as you like. You can also use *Comment Line* on the *Comment & Number* tab to highlight from a word to the end of the line (check Treat keyword as symbol for partial word match).
3. Select `Language` > `User-Defined`

If you want to use this highlighting scheme regularly, you can save it by clicking `Save As...`. This scheme should now be listed under the `Language` menu of the main Notepad++ window.

Comment: almost but no cigar... I really need to highlight certain lines in a log file. not certain words or from a word onward...

Comment: @Jonathan > by following directions gave by Žiga Stegu answer and adding it in Operators and delimiters tab, I've been able to highlight whole lines.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same need. "Highlighting lines that contain specific keywords". I currently use  [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) or better: [Glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/) for this, but it would be nice to see this in Notepad++.

I generally use Notepad++ to browse through log files. Certain events start with specific keywords; line highlighting in Notepad++ would allow me to quickly find the events in the log.

Answer (score 6):

As stated before me:

> Select Language > Define your language... (or View Language > User-Defined Dialog..., or Language > User-Defined, depending on version and localisation file)

In my case. I needed to color code lines starting with "V"{tab}
I set Delimiter 1 style:

- Open: V
- Escape:
- Close:((EOL))

This would highlight also mid text V and on, so I copied a {tab} into

Open: V{tab}  //{tab} is not visible but present

I found out that {tab} is in exported .xml encoded as `&#x0009;` which stands for http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x0009/index.html exactly what I needed. So by modifing the xml with unicode caracter codes

Comment: This has to be done in the "Operators and delimiters" tab to work

Comment: it does not colorize/style the entire line (or to the end of the line) as was asked

Answer (score 3):

There's a plugin for N++ now called [AnalysePlugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/analyseplugin/) that might fit the bill.  It allows for normal, regex, and escaped searches.  It dumps results to another pane but you can color foreground and background properties of the results as well as save and load filter sets.